# VBA Macro to split sheets

Tags: vba, excel

so I have VBA code to do this:

1. Copy from worksheet "Sheet1" column A1:L1001
2. Paste them in worksheet "paste"
3. Clean cells (some cells had "" in them)
4. Remove any blank rows
5. Copy data from "paste" A1:L1001
6. Create new workbook in designated location, rename worksheet with date stamp, paste data from "paste" sheet and save the sheet

Now I want to add another step between 4-5 steps to:
4a. Count column A:A and if A:A>100 lines then split into another workbook and save it with a [date_stamp]_2 or whatever.

So if workbooks contains 340 line there will be 4 workbooks 1-100 lines 101-200, 201-300 and 301-340 lines.

Anyone any ideas?

Something like count A:A, if A:A>100, then take A1:L100, then count from A101:A1001 if >100 then A1 (header) A101:L200 ...

'~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

```
'~~> Copy A Range of Data
    Worksheets("OPT_REPORT").Range("A1:M1001").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy

'~~> PasteSpecial Values Only
    Worksheets("paste").Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats

'~~> Clear Clipboard
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

'~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

```
'~~> Find "" and replace with pneumonoultramicroscopicsilicovolcanoconiosis

    Worksheets("paste").Range("A1:M1001").Cells.Replace What:="", Replacement:="pneumonoultramicroscopicsilicovolcanoconiosis", LookAt:= _
    xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
    ReplaceFormat:=False

'~~> Find pneumonoultramicroscopicsilicovolcanoconiosis and replace with ""

    Worksheets("paste").Range("A1:M1001").Cells.Replace What:="pneumonoultramicroscopicsilicovolcanoconiosis", Replacement:="", LookAt:= _
    xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
    ReplaceFormat:=False
```

'~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

```
'~~> Finds a space in column A and deletes entire row

    On Error Resume Next
    Worksheets("paste").Columns("A").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
```

'~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

```
    Dim wbI As Workbook, wbO As Workbook
    Dim wsI As Worksheet, wsO As Worksheet
    Date1 = Now()

'~~> Source/Input Workbook

    Set wbI = ThisWorkbook

'~~> Set the relevant sheet from where you want to copy

    Set wsI = wbI.Sheets("paste")

'~~> Destination/Output Workbook

    Set wbO = Workbooks.Add

With wbO
    '~~> Set the relevant sheet to where you want to paste
    Set wsO = wbO.Sheets("Sheet1")

    '~~>. Save the file
    .SaveAs Filename:="C:\FILES\Test_" & Format(Date1, "ddmmyyyy-hhmmss") & ".xls", FileFormat:=56

    '~~> Copy the range
    wsI.Range("A1:M1001").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy

    '~~> Paste it in say Cell A1. Change as applicable
    wsO.Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats, Operation:=xlNone, _
    SkipBlanks:=True, Transpose:=False
```

'~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

```
    Workbooks("Test_" & Format(Date1, "ddmmyyyy-hhmmss") & ".xls").Close SaveChanges:=True
```

'~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

```
    Sheets("paste").Range("A1:M1001").Clear
```

'~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

```
    MsgBox "File Saved"
```

'~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Comment: Freedox, please keep in mind that this is not a free code-writing service. Yet, we are eager to help fellow programmers (and aspirants) writing their own code. Read the help topics on [How do I Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You might also want to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and earn a badge while doing so. Afterwards, please update your question with the VBA code you have written thus far in order to complete the task(s) you wish to achieve.

Comment: For the least, show your existing code so that you can have suggestions on how to modify it.

Comment: sorry guys... didn't wanted to paste my code as it's quite longe... but you are right... will do that :) once again, apologies... I don't want anyone to write a code for me just a pointing to the right direcion would do...

Comment: Just added the code and have the split into steps... not the cleanest way to do things but like to have them clear...

Comment: You got a good sugestion below. If that doen't solve your problem, please add a comment to indicate the reasons.

Answer (score 1):

If i were you, i would check if the 101th cell has data, then the 201th cell...
Asuming that Column A has always data until the last row, you can do sth like the following code:

```
Dim row as integer: row = 1
Do while NOT IsEmpty(Sheet("paste").cells(row,1))
    'Here goes the code from steps 5 to 6, saving the cells: "A" & row & ":L" & row+99
    'ex.: A1:L100, A101:L200, and so on...
    row = row +100
Loop
```